# Recursively traverse an object instance (that has heavily nested custom objects) using java reflection APIs

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, reflection, java-8

I am looking a library or code snippet, that helps me Recursively traverse an object instance (that has heavily nested custom objects) using java reflection APIs.

**NOTE** :- Im looking for code snippet that traverses an object rather than a class footprint.

**Example**

```
 public class GetAddOnSubscriptionsRequest {
    @NonNull private String subscriptionId;

    private StatusFilter statusFilter;

    @NonNull private Long pageSize;

    @NonNull private Long offset;
    
    private GetAddOnSubscriptionsOutput addOnSubscriptionsOutput;
}

public enum StatusFilter {
    CreationPending,
    ApprovalPending,
    Active,
    Paused,
    Cancelled,
    FulfillmentPending,
    PaymentPending,
    Suspended;
}

public class GetAddOnSubscriptionsOutput {
    private AddOnSubscription addOnSubscriptions;
    private Long totalAddOnSubscriptionsCount;
}

public class AddOnSubscription {
    private String subscriptionID;
    private String serviceProviderID;
    private BeneficiaryExternalID ownerID;
    private String customerID;
    private String marketplaceID;
    private List<String> addOnIDs;
    private Boolean hasActiveAdjustment;
    private Date subscriptionStartDate;
    private String asin;
    private String offerListingID;
    private Boolean autoRenewEnabled;
    private Boolean hasOpenProblems;
    private Long maxNumberOfBeneficiaries;
    private Long currentContractPeriod;
    private Date contractPeriodStartDate;
    private Date contractEndDate;
    private Long currentBillingPeriod;
    private Date billingPeriodStartDate;
    private Date nextBillDate;
    private Date statusStartDate;
    private Date expectedStatusEndDate;
    private Long gracePeriodBeforeCancellation;
    private String cachedDocumentID;
    private String cachedDocumentDomain;
    private String planID;
    private String planGroupID;
    private String baseCurrencyCode;
    private BigDecimal nextBillAmount;
    private String billingScheduleID;
    private String sourceID;
    private String sourceType;
    private String preferedPaymentPlanID;
    private Boolean currentPlanGifted;
    private String cancellationReason;
    private Boolean walletEnabled;
    private Boolean acceptedTermsAndConditions;
    private String status;
    private List<String> systemTags;
    private Boolean isInSyncWithBaseSubscription;
    private String baseSubscriptionID;
}

public class BeneficiaryExternalID {
    private String id;
    private String idType;
}
```

> GetAddOnSubscriptionsRequest.class —> This is class footprint

```
    GetAddOnSubscriptionsRequest addOnSubscriptionsRequest = new GetAddOnSubscriptionsRequest()

                .setSubscriptionId("1234578")
                .setOffset(Long.valueOf(0))
                .setPageSize(Long.valueOf(50))

                .setAddOnSubscriptionsOutput(
                        new GetAddOnSubscriptionsOutput.Builder()
                                .setTotalAddOnSubscriptionsCount()
                                .setAddOnSubscriptions(
                                        new AddOnSubscription.Builder()
                                                .setAsin()
                                                .setAddOnIDs()
                                                .setBaseSubscriptionID()
                                                .setCachedDocumentID()
                                                .setHasOpenProblems()
                                                .build()
                                ).build());
```

> addOnSubscriptionsRequest -> This is object

Now applying reflection on GetAddOnSubscriptionsRequest.class [class footprint] is different from addOnSubscriptionsRequest [object instance] So, i am looking for applying reflection and recursively traverse all the nodes of my object instance. While traverse, i want to check what all fields have got null/non-null and accordingly apply some logic on top of it, to full-fill my use case.

NOTE:- if you are wondering why my setters are not taking in any input, its because i have hand-coded those explicitly to take some default values.

TIA.

Comment: "i am looking for applying reflection and recursively traverse all the nodes of my object instance" <-- Your `Student` object is not recursive at all, nor does it have any "nodes". Please edit your question to describe more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Recursive traversal could give your `String.value` and `Double.value`, which would be no improvement over treating the `String` and `Double` values as atomic (e.g. printing their `toString()` content). Moreover, these classes are `final`, so it’s impossible that actual objects have a different type than the fields’ declared types. The code for a dynamic traversal wouldn’t differ much from the static traversal (it’s dealing with `java.lang.Class` and `java.lang.reflect.Field` in either case) and here, even the result wouldn’t differ much.

Comment: I’ve never heard the term “class footprint” and what you’ve posted, is just an application of the Builder Pattern. It’s not clear what relevance this code snippet is supposed to have. Traversing an object graph via Reflection is a no-brainer. `getClass()`/`getDeclaredFields()`/`getSuperclass()`/ (`Field`)`get(Object)`, just go ahead and come back when there’s an actual problem.

Comment: @Holger can i text you and discuss this personally ?

Comment: @Holger actually, i am getting struck at a place where lets say initially i made a call to getDeclaredFields() and i got 4 custom fields. Now i want to check if value at each of those fields and if its non-null, then only i want to traverse each of the field types recursively.  I am not able to get the code snippet for it